# DVI-I output detected as DVI-D causes display to be detected, but stays black

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dvi

I have connected an old HP monitor as my secondary display with a D-SUB cable connected to D-SUB-DVI-I adapter.
The display stays black, even though it is correctly detected. 
I'm 99% sure that the cause is the DVI-I output on my GPU being treated as DVI-D therefore sending only digital signal (instead of analog) to the D-SUB cable, which the monitor can't read. 
Is there any way to somewhat make the DVI-I port treated as DVI-I instead of DVI-D?

It also doesn't work when the main HDMI display is unplugged.
Everything works just fine under Windows.

[Xrandr output. The DVI-I being detected as DVI-D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOQn0.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way without "active" hardware to "treat" DVI-D (digital) signal as DVI-I (analog) signal. You need some kind of converter, not just a socket adapter.
Many converters exist on the market - the deciding factors are the build quality and the maximum resolution and refresh rate that is supported by the converter. If you have other output ports on the video card (GPU) such as HDMI and/or Display Port, you may look for converters from HDMI to VGA (D-SUB) or DP to VGA respectively. Since in any case a digital signal has to be transformed to analog signal you are not necessarily limited to use DVI to VGA.